# How to use Loop to execute store procedure in Cosmos-DB/Document-DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, azure-cosmosdb

I have JSON like

```
{
  "id": "58d99ca3231f13b9ecbbbca4",
  "50records": [
    {
      "aomsLineNbr": 1,
      "licenses": [
        {
          "productKey": "84fc2cde-9735-4cea-b97a-3cd627d3d0a5",
          "aid": "someAid"   
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- I want to fetch record on the basis of `aid`.
- `50record` can have multiple objects and `licenses` can also have multiple objects.
- I am constucting the query as
  `"SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o['50records'][0].licenses[0].aid='someAid'"`
- how can I loop those `50records` and `licenses` to search `aid` in all available objects?

Below is my store procedure:

```
function getOrdersByAidCollection(aid){
var context = getContext();
var collection = context.getCollection();
var link = collection.getSelfLink();
var response = context.getResponse();

var query = "SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o['50records'][0].licenses[0].aid='"+aid+"'";

var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(),query,
function (err, feed, options) {
    if (err) {
        return errorResponse(400, err.message);
    }
    if (!feed || !feed.length){
        return errorResponse(400, "no orders doc found");
    }else { 
       getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(feed));
    }
});

    if (!isAccepted){
        return errorResponse(400, "The query was not accepted by the server.");
    }


}
```

Where and how I need to put a loop ??

Any help will be appreciable!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you need a loop? This looks like a query question. Can you try a query like this:

```
SELECT VALUE r
FROM orders c
JOIN r in c["50records"]
JOIN li in r.licenses
WHERE li.aid = "someAid"
```

Thanks!